# Problem compiling Python 2.6.4 on AIX 5.3

Tags: python, compilation, aix, ncurses

I'm trying to build Python 2.6.4 on AIX 5.3. I'm running configure like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/chenf/python --disable-ipv6 --disable-shared --with-libs='/usr/lib/libncurses.a' --without-threads --disable-threads --with-ncurses=/utv/sad/ncurses/lib/libncurses.a
```

I seem to be having linking problems with ncurses (see below), which is why I've tried in multiple ways to point out to configure where to find libncurses.a. /usr/lib/libncurses.a is a symbolic link to /utv/sad/ncurses/lib/libncurses.a, which exists and has no permission problems. There is also a link to that file in /usr/local/lib.

My problem is that I get the following errors from make:

```
running build
running build_ext
INFO: Can't locate Tcl/Tk libs and/or headers
building '_curses' extension
./Modules/ld_so_aix gcc -bI:Modules/python.exp build/temp.aix-5.3-2.6/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/_cursesmodule.o -L/usr/local/lib -lncurses -o build/lib.aix-5.3-2.6/_curses.so
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: _unctrl
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .setsyx
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: ._setqiflush
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .initscr32
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: wacs_map
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: ._getsyx
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .getattrs
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .w32attrset
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .w32insch
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .p32echochar
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .w32echochar
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .getcury
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .getcurx
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .box32
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .w32attron
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .w32attroff
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .w32addch
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .getpary
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .getparx
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .getmaxy
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .getmaxx
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .getbegy
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .getbegx
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
collect2: ld returned 8 exit status
building 'zlib' extension
./Modules/ld_so_aix gcc -bI:Modules/python.exp build/temp.aix-5.3-2.6/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/zlibmodule.o -L/usr/local/lib -lz -o build/lib.aix-5.3-2.6/zlib.so
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .inflateCopy
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
collect2: ld returned 8 exit status
building 'bz2' extension
gcc -DNDEBUG -O -I. -I/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/./Include -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I/usr/local/include -I/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Include -I/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4 -c /home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c -o build/temp.aix-5.3-2.6/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.o
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:12:19: bzlib.h: No such file or directory
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:111: error: parse error before "BZFILE"
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:111: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:118: error: parse error before '}' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:118: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:122: error: parse error before "bz_stream"
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:122: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:127: error: parse error before '}' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:127: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:131: error: parse error before "bz_stream"
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:131: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:137: error: parse error before '}' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:137: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `Util_CatchBZ2Error':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:147: error: `BZ_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:147: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:147: error: for each function it appears in.)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:148: error: `BZ_STREAM_END' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:160: error: `BZ_PARAM_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:167: error: `BZ_MEM_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:172: error: `BZ_DATA_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:173: error: `BZ_DATA_ERROR_MAGIC' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:178: error: `BZ_IO_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:183: error: `BZ_UNEXPECTED_EOF' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:190: error: `BZ_SEQUENCE_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:229: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `Util_GetLine':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:239: error: `f' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:243: error: `n' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:265: error: `BZ_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:282: error: `BZ_STREAM_END' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:325: error: parse error before "BZFILE"
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `Util_UnivNewlineRead':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:328: error: `buf' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:334: error: `f' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:335: error: `bzerror' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:335: error: `stream' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:335: error: `n' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:380: error: `BZ_STREAM_END' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:392: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `Util_DropReadAhead':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:394: error: `f' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:402: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `Util_ReadAhead':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:407: error: `f' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:418: error: `bufsize' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:427: error: `BZ_STREAM_END' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:430: error: `BZ_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:443: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `Util_ReadAheadGetLineSkip':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:450: error: `f' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:451: error: `bufsize' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:457: error: `skip' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:498: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2File_read':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:505: error: `args' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:509: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:549: error: `BZ_STREAM_END' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:553: error: `BZ_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:585: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2File_readline':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:590: error: `args' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:594: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:630: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2File_readlines':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:647: error: `args' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:651: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:677: error: `BZ_STREAM_END' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:685: error: `BZ_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:792: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2File_write':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:800: error: `args' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:806: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:828: error: `BZ_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:852: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2File_writelines':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:863: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:878: error: `seq' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:953: error: `BZ_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:990: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2File_seek':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1004: error: `args' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1016: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1046: error: `BZ_STREAM_END' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1048: error: `BZ_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1143: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2File_tell':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1147: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1172: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2File_close':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1175: error: `BZ_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1178: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1204: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1225: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2File_get_newlines':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1227: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1254: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2File_get_closed':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1256: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1260: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2File_get_mode':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1262: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1266: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2File_get_name':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1268: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1291: error: parse error before ')' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1291: error: initializer element is not constant
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1291: error: (near initialization for `BZ2File_members[0].offset')
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1292: error: initializer element is not constant
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1292: error: (near initialization for `BZ2File_members[0]')
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1293: error: initializer element is not constant
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1293: error: (near initialization for `BZ2File_members[1]')
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1300: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2File_init':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1311: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1313: error: `args' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1313: error: `kwargs' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1390: error: `BZ_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1412: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2File_dealloc':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1419: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1440: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2File_getiter':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1442: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1454: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2File_iternext':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1458: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1554: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2Comp_compress':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1562: error: `bz_stream' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1562: error: `bzs' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1562: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1565: error: `args' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1595: error: `BZ_RUN' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1597: error: `BZ_RUN_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1636: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2Comp_flush':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1640: error: `bz_stream' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1640: error: `bzs' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1640: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1663: error: `BZ_FINISH' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1665: error: `BZ_STREAM_END' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1667: error: `BZ_FINISH_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1707: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2Comp_init':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1713: error: `args' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1713: error: `kwargs' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1731: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1731: error: `bz_stream' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1733: error: `BZ_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1752: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2Comp_dealloc':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1758: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1826: error: parse error before ')' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1826: error: initializer element is not constant
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1826: error: (near initialization for `BZ2Decomp_members[0].offset')
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1826: error: initializer element is not constant
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1826: error: (near initialization for `BZ2Decomp_members[0]')
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1827: error: initializer element is not constant
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1827: error: (near initialization for `BZ2Decomp_members[1]')
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1845: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2Decomp_decompress':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1853: error: `bz_stream' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1853: error: `bzs' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1853: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1856: error: `args' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1883: error: `BZ_STREAM_END' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1893: error: `BZ_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1936: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2Decomp_init':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1940: error: `args' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1951: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1955: error: `bz_stream' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1957: error: `BZ_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: At top level:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1978: error: parse error before '*' token
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `BZ2Decomp_dealloc':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:1984: error: `self' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `bz2_compress':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:2065: error: `bz_stream' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:2065: error: parse error before "_bzs"
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:2066: error: `bzs' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:2066: error: `_bzs' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:2102: error: `BZ_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:2111: error: `BZ_FINISH' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:2113: error: `BZ_STREAM_END' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:2115: error: `BZ_FINISH_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c: In function `bz2_decompress':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:2158: error: `bz_stream' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:2158: error: parse error before "_bzs"
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:2159: error: `bzs' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:2159: error: `_bzs' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:2186: error: `BZ_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/bz2module.c:2197: error: `BZ_STREAM_END' undeclared (first use in this function)
building '_multiprocessing' extension
gcc -DNDEBUG -O -DHAVE_SEM_OPEN=1 -DHAVE_FD_TRANSFER=1 -DHAVE_SEM_TIMEDWAIT=1 -IModules/_multiprocessing -I. -I/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/./Include -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I/usr/local/include -I/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Include -I/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4 -c /home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/_multiprocessing/socket_connection.c -o build/temp.aix-5.3-2.6/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/_multiprocessing/socket_connection.o
In file included from /home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/_multiprocessing/socket_connection.c:202:
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/_multiprocessing/connection.h: In function `connection_poll':
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/_multiprocessing/connection.h:357: error: `_save' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/_multiprocessing/connection.h:357: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Modules/_multiprocessing/connection.h:357: error: for each function it appears in.)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup.py", line 1910, in 
    main()
  File "./setup.py", line 1905, in main
    'Lib/smtpd.py']
  File "/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Lib/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Lib/distutils/command/build.py", line 134, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Lib/distutils/cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "./setup.py", line 201, in build_extensions
    build_ext.build_extensions(self)
  File "/home/chenf/python-src/Python-2.6.4/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "./setup.py", line 234, in build_extension
    if not self.configure_ctypes(ext):
  File "./setup.py", line 1715, in configure_ctypes
    ffi_srcdir = os.path.join(fficonfig['ffi_srcdir'], 'src')
KeyError: 'ffi_srcdir'
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.


Stop.
```

The thing about not being able to locate Tcl/Tk is not a problem, I don't need those.

However, curses, which is the following problem, IS a problem. I need that. If I interpret things correctly, it can't find libncurses.a. At least, all the listed "Undefined symbols" look like ncurses functions to me. But maybe I'm wrong, maybe it does find the libncurses.a file, but can't find the symbols in it? I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like bzip2 isn't able to find itself, either -- sometimes you see weird Python build errors when you wander too far from GCC.  My first gut recommendation would be to compile with GCC, GNU binutils, and GNU make, and see if the problem persists.

Also, when you're talking to `configure`, it'll figure out the name of the library from your configure option.  Therefore, this:

```
--with-ncurses=/utv/sad/ncurses/lib/libncurses.a
```

Should be:

```
--with-ncurses=/utv/sad/ncurses/lib
```

But that also implies that the headers can be found there. Can they?

There may also be an option to your platform's compiler to add a directory for libs -- since, in this case, Python is trying to use `-lncurses` before it compiles the extension (making the linker search for libncurses.a in the library search path).

Comment: Thanks for your respone. I'll try it when I get back to work on Monday. I believe I am using gcc, but I'll check to make sure. Also, I'll install GNU tools as you suggest, and try with them instead. I'll comment again when I've done this.

Comment: It doesn't? But it says "gcc" in the output I included above?
No matter. Thanks to your advice, I got it to work. Thanks! I'll see if I can post an answer to this question myself with details of the steps I had to take, for the benefit of others who might have the same problem.

Comment: @Enfors: Sorry, should have clarified that `ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .setsyx` is not GNU ld.  Looks like you may have been using GCC for other parts, though.  Glad you got it working. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is so old problem(2009 ??)..but I meet the same problem today!!
For other AIX users like me...I will leave my case

OK..first, Check your environmental variable OBJECT_MODE.

In my case, OBJECT_MODE was 64,  but the archive file libcurses.a contains
only 32bit object files!!

After changing the environmental variable OBJECT_MODE to 32, everything worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jed Smith's suggestions, I've managed to get this to work. This is what I did accomplish this:

- **Step one:** First, I edited "Makefile.pre.in". I replaced the line "CC=   @CC@" with "CC=   gcc". As far as I can tell, this forced the compilation to use gcc instead of whatever other unnamable hideousness AIX tried to use.
- **Step two:** Put a soft link for ncurses.h under /usr/include.
  I couldn't get configure to find ncurses.h under /opt/utv/sad/include/ncurses/, so I cheated;  I ran the following command as root:

```
ln -s /utv/sad/ncurses/include/ncurses/ncurses.h /usr/include/ncurses.h
```

- **Step three:**
  I compiled and installed GNU binutils and GNU make, configuring them with "--prefix=/home/chenf". Then I put /home/chenf/bin first in my path, to make sure the compilation process would use whatever it found there instead of the defaults provides by AIX.
- **Step four:** I ran configure like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/freeware --disable-ipv6 --without-threads --with-ncurses=/opt/sad/ncurses
```

Ipv6 and threads were giving me compilation errors, and I don't need them, so that's why I disabled them. Under the /opt/sad/ncurses directory, lib/libncurses.a is found. That seems to have taken care of the library itself.

After that, all I had to do was "make" and "make install". Done.

I did get some errors during compilation, and in the end I was told that it had failed to produce some of the modules (like math, and datetime) but that everything else was still OK. For the time being I'll make do without them.